# How to change the text from a textfield from a different class in WindowsForm

Tags: c#, winforms

For a project I am trying to change the text of a RichTextBox using a method from a different class. However when trying to pass a string through, it doesn't change the text but when I write `Console.Writeline`, it does show up.

What I think the problem is, is that I have to refresh the `WindowsForm` before the text can change.

```
namespace RichTextBox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             addText.returnText();
         }

        public void addData(string s)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(s);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

And the other class:

```
namespace RichTextBox
{
    class addText
    {
        public static void returnText()
        {
            string s = "test test;";
            Form1 f = new Form1();
            f.addData(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your returnText method is creating a new Form1, it shouldn't.  There are a few options here, you could update the signature to expect a Form1 instance - `returnText(Form1 f)` and pass the current form instance to the method ( `addText.returnText(this);`

Or, and preferably, have the `returnText` method do exactly what it says - return the text, the calling code can update the rich text box.  It keeps the responsibilities separate and clearer.

```
public static string returnText()
{
 string s = "test test;";
 return s;
}
```

calling code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var s = addText.returnText();
addData(s);
}
```

Comment: yea, I just figured it out that when in button1_click() the richtextbox does change from text. So I tried returning which helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try debugging your code and you'll see that the text of the RichTextBox in the `addText` class is set. Only... it is another instance of `Form1` and not your current shown form. Add following line in the `returnText` method to see this:

```
f.Show();
```

Pass the form as a parameter to the class and then this will work. In the button click event, change the line to following:

```
addText.returnText(this);
```

And the `returnText` method looks like this:

```
public static void returnText(Form1 form)
{
    string s = "test test;";
    form.addData(s);
}
```

But better would be to return a value from the class and set that value in the richtextbox in the form class:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(addText.returnText());
    // OR
    addData(addText.returnText());
}

public static string returnText()
{
    string s = "test test;";
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Why is the second one better? Is it faster or does it only help for easy reading?

Comment: To understand, best to read some articles on `single responsability principle` and `separation of concerns`.